# How to have just 2 lines per page

Tags: geometry

A LaTeX file

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\linesperpage{2}
\begin{document}
    line1
    line2
    line3
    line4
\end{document}
```

I hope can give the `linesperpage`, and the output file only 2 line per page.

Comment: Do you mean something like `\usepackage[textheight=2\baselineskip]{geometry}`? Or do you want the PDF to be that size too? And what about headers and footers, etc.?

Comment: Alternatively, \baselineskip=0.5\textheight or perhaps slightly smaller.

Comment: The question title is impressive, I must say :)

Comment: i want the pdf size always A4 paper @jon

Comment: where do you want the two lines positioned on the page?  both at the top; one at the top and one at the bottom; or some other locations?

Comment: Have you tried my suggestion, then? If so and it's not doing what you require, you should explain what else needs to be modified. As it is, your question is somewhat underspecified.

Comment: o, thanks @jon, my first problem solved. and the seconde is when `\documentclass{beamer}` and 
    \begin{frame}{frametitle}
    line1

    line2

    line3

    line4
    \end{frame}
how can i get the same effect?

Comment: the frametitle at the top of every frame is better :)

Comment: For `beamer`, you should ask a new question, especially since `beamer` documents are very different from those produced by the standard classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) to adjust the page layout.

If you want two lines per page *and* the paper height to be the same, then use

```
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  textheight  = 2\baselineskip,
  paperheight = 2\baselineskip
}
\pagestyle{empty}
```

If you want two lines per page with the original header/footer space, then use

```
\usepackage{geometry}
\makeatletter
\newlength{\Gm@@tmargin}\setlength{\Gm@@tmargin}{\Gm@tmargin}% Original top margin (which includes header)
\newlength{\Gm@@bmargin}\setlength{\Gm@@bmargin}{\Gm@bmargin}% Original bottom margin (which includes footer)
\geometry{
  textheight  = 2\baselineskip,
  paperheight = \dimexpr\Gm@@tmargin+2\baselineskip+\Gm@@bmargin
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: i want the pdf paper size always A4

Comment: @ZenoShuai: Then use `paper = a4paper` instead of the `paperheight = ..` part. The two lines will be roughly in the middle of the page vertically.

Comment: thanks @Wnrner, can you try when `\documentclass{beamer}` and 
    \begin{frame}{frametitle}
    line1

    line2

    line3

    line4
    \end{frame}
how can get the same effect?

Comment: @ZenoShuai: Ahhh... you're using [`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer). That's different, as a `frame` consists of a title (and possibly a subtitle) together with unique-created headers/footers. Moreover, `beamer`'s page size is not A4. If you're using the regular overlay specifications of `beamer`, then you add `<1>` to only show that content on slide number `1`, or `<2>` to show it on slide `2`, etc. My suggestion is to [ask a follow-up question](http://goo.gl/vWjuk) as the question you now pose may require a completely different solution.